# How do I create a fade in effect on a rotating background image using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, image-rotation

I'm currently using a small jquery script to rotate through background images on a portfolio site I''m creating for a friend's portfolio site here's the code:

```
  counter = 1; 
    num_images = 9;
    dir = "IMAGE DIRECTORY URL";

    function rotateHeader() {


 var background_img = 'url(' + dir + '/image' + counter + '.gif)';

 jQuery('.category').css('background-image', background_img);  
 counter++; if (counter > num_images) counter = 1;

    }
    setInterval( "rotateHeader()", 5000 );
```

You can see it working here:

[www.iamanatom.com/site/the-good](http://www.iamanatom.com/site/the-good)

What I want to do is have the images and or colors fade in and out. I think I'll have to preload the images to do this and then add some sort of fade property when the pictures are loading. 
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ought to do it

```
var counter = 1, 
    num_images = 9,
    dir = "IMAGE DIRECTORY URL";

function rotateHeader() {

    var background_img = 'url(' + dir + '/image' + counter + '.gif)';

    jQuery('.category').fadeOut(function() {
        jQuery(this).css('background-image', background_img).fadeIn();
    });  
    counter++; if (counter > num_images) counter = 1;
}
setInterval(rotateHeader, 5000 );
```

First we fade out the current background image, then in the callback function, change the background image and then fade it back in. You might want to play with the `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` intervals to get the effect you want. I've also changed the `setInterval()` to use the function name as opposed to a string to evaluate.

Comment: Okay amazing thanks you so much, thats created the fade effect BUT now I have another problem - if you look at my implementation:
www.iamanatom.com/site/the-good

you will see that the entire page fades in and out rather than just the backgroun images. Not sure what to do about that!

Comment: Ahhh I think I know why that is - the element I'm trying to manipulate is the body (I'm using category as a class because I only want the effect on the blog pages). Unfortunately this element wraps around everything so it fades the whole page in.

I think my solution will be to create an absolutely positioned div that dynamically picks up the classes I need and is outside the main page elements... we'll see if this works